# Jira API How to Populate automatically Description field when new issue gets created for a project

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Using Jira API and python I want to Populate automatically the Description field with a template like the one below, every time a new issue is created for an specific project:

Some Bold Text: Some Bold Text

Some Bold Text: Some Text

Some Italic text

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a rather convoluted solution for a simple problem. Why not just create an automation rule in Jira to do the task?